# Minimal Surface of Revolution - Integrate Challenge

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, trigonometry, variational-calculus

I'm trying to use Mathematica to go from equation (11) to equation (12) in this example of a [Minimal Surface of Revolution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimalSurfaceofRevolution.html). There is a MMA notebook on that link, but it only shows how to find the roots of equation (12) and calculate the surface area - it does not show how to calculate equation (12).

Here is equation (11) from Wolfram link above:

$$
x = a \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{y^2-a^2}} = a \cosh^{-1}(\frac{y}{a})+b
$$

Solving for $y$ yields:

$$
y = a \cosh(\frac{x-b}{a})
$$

I am trying to replicate this in Mathematica. Here is what I have tried:

```
firstInt = a Integrate[1/Sqrt[y^2-a^2], y]
```

This outputs a long expression containing `Log` terms. From here, I try two approaches (1) I simply solve for `y`, and (2) I use `ExpToTrig` to convert the result of the integral to an expression with trigonometric functions via:

```
trigInt = ExpToTrig[firstInt]
```

The two approaches yield identical solutions:

```
sol1 = Solve[x + b == firstInt, y]
```

yields:

$$
y = \pm i a \sinh(\frac{x+b}{a})
$$

and,

```
sol2 = Solve[x + b == trigInt, y]
```

yields:

$$
y = \pm a \frac{\tanh(\frac{x+b}{a})}{\sqrt{\tanh^2(\frac{x+b}{a})-1}}
$$

These equations are identical (at least, they yield the same result for arbitrarily chosen values of `a`, `b`, and `x`). These expressions produce imaginary solutions, and they are not equal the actual catenary expression: $y = a \cosh(\frac{x-b}{a})$.

I have also tried placing restrictions on `a` and `y` in the integrate, such that they are both positive, nonzero, and real, but no luck. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are computing an antiderivative. It can have arbitrary piecewise constants of integration. If you can recast as a definite integral, the assumptions on parameters may then be usable inside `Integrate`.

Comment: Going back to Wolfram Mathworld's solution to the problem, what assumptions are they making about the constants? To put another way - I am teaching this in a class, how can a student use MMA to reproduce the solution?

Comment: Try this: `Assuming[y > a > 0, FullSimplify[Solve[x == FullSimplify[a Integrate[1/Sqrt[t^2 - a^2], {t, a, y}]] + b, y]]]`

Comment: Excellent this (mostly) works! I get: `a Coth[(b-x)/a]/sqrt[Csch[(b-x)/a]^2]` which is equivalent to `a Cosh[(x-b)/a]`.  I cannot figure out what identities to use to show they are equivalent, and MMA's `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` do not help.